# Pulled Pork Jackfruit

Tags: fruit, pork, vegan, jackfruit

When cooking jackfruit for “pulled pork” from canned young green jackfruit, do you cut off the core from the rest of it or just braise it till tender?

Comment: if you pull jackfruit, wouldn't that be "pulled jackfruit" instead?

Answer (score 3):

I use two forks to shred the jackfruit - core and all. The core pieces have a bit more firm texture so it's a nice mix with the rest of it.

Comment: Sometimes I need to chop the core a bit with a knife due to toughness, but shredding with forks is the way to go